# Squatting Vanity Urls

Tags: support, jobs, vanity-url

It seems that someone has squatted the vanity url http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jonskeet.  I demand justice.

**Edit**
It would appear that justice has been delivered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/493/lomaxx (Phil Bernie apparently)

Answer (score 6):

In all seriousness, this could be a real issue. I haven't been to the Careers site yet, mostly because I'm very happy in my current job, but just looking at the "Jon Skeet" URL, that's pretty spectacularly crummy on the part of the squatter. No amount of ponies and waffles could make up for this kind of fraudulent behavior.

I wonder if there ought to be -- or even if it's feasible to implement -- a check when you request the vanity URL that compares it against existing usernames, and if it matches any (and does not match your own, to gracefully handle dupes), disallow it?

The big issue I can foresee is that, as the systems grow in popularity, there would be a performance problem for performing that check. Probably a large one. :(

Perhaps a means of reporting this sort of thing might be the easiest answer?

**EDIT**

Took out the Sara Chipps part on account of Tom Ritter's explanation in a comment to another answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is totally **not a problem**.

Careers is managed by Jeff, not ICANN. Abuse can be handled swiftly and promptly.

Answer (score 3):

Not like Jon Skeet needs it in the near future. (I would guess)

Answer (score 0):

Also SaraChipps:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/sarachipps

Probably others as well. Mine name remains open ;)

Comment: Not for long!! :)

Comment: It's hilarious how much flack I got for this.  After she tweeted it - someone literally started trying to hack my website. I nabbed it as a joke when we were talking about it in *her* WAN Party - I'm obviously going to give it back to her, I'm waiting for her to get a CV ready so no one else squats it and to give time for everyone to see the joke. Yeesh!

Comment: @Tom Ritter: Thanks for the explanation; I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

How can http://careers.stackoverflow.com/dan not be a page but be taken?
And I've been refreshing careers every day for two weeks to get http://careers.stackoverflow.com/daniel and someone beats me to it anyway.

Comment: It can be reserved but not visible to the public.